# Affect a JS function to a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im struggling with it for now too long.

Here is the idea : 
I have a tabpane bootstrap according to [the doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events) I linked an event with :
`$('[data-value="croisiere"]').on('shown.bs.tab',function(){....})`

In this tabpane I have a datepicker. The struggle is to relink my function every time my datepicker is updated.

Basicaly this is it :

```
$('[data-value="croisiere"]').on('shown.bs.tab',function(){
  console.log("LaunchFunction");
   $('#cruise-tab [class*="glyphicon-chevron"]').on('click', function(){
      console.log('Why is it only working once?');
  }); 
});
```

**So how could I say if this particular part of the DOM change reaffect my function ?**

If you want to try the code you can have a go [there](http://dev.agencedevoyage.com/). You will have to click on the tab "croisière" from the motor.

Comment: Your site has some Jquery errors, Try clearing it out and then check .

Comment: Its ok I found a way, it probably came from conflict between plugin.

Comment: glad you found your way through..

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference a higher selector to create the event handler that gets attached to the parent element - that is not affected directly by the dynamic content addition:

```
   $('body').on('click','#cruise-tab [class*="glyphicon-chevron"]', function(){
      console.log('This should work')...
```

Comment: Strangely it is not working It react as if the element does not exist. However when I just look for `$('#cruise-tab [class*="glyphicon-chevron"]')` in the console it told me the element exist.